# Can I add an iPad popover programatically?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, ipad

Is it possible to add a popover programatically without using a NIB file? All the examples I have run into use NIB files.

Any information/help/examples would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [UIPopoverController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html).
Init it with a content view controller (any `UIViewController` subclass that shows your content), and afterwards you can show it with:

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromRect:(CGRect)rect inView:(UIView *)view permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
- (void)presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)item permittedArrowDirections:(UIPopoverArrowDirection)arrowDirections animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Comment: Thanks V1ru8!
Worked perfectly - Much appreciated.